# JQuery Login, hit enter to login

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My login form in the HTML looks like this:

```
  <div id="login">      
    <label for="email_B">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_B" id="email_B" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password_B" name="password_B" id="password_B" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign in" />
  </div>
```

My JQuery is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() //a

var login = function() {//b
        var emailB = encodeURIComponent($('#email_B').val());  
        var passwordB = encodeURIComponent($('#password_B').val());  
        $('#content').fadeOut();
        $('#login_effect').fadeIn( function(){//c   
            $.ajax({//d 
                type: 'POST', url: 'checklogin.php',  dataType: "json",  data: { email: emailB, password: passwordB,  },
                success: function(result) { //e                     
                    if (!result.success) { timeout = setTimeout(function(){ $('#login_effect').fadeOut(); }, 2500); document.location.href='wrongpassword/'; } 
                    else { timeout = setTimeout(function(){ $('#login_effect').fadeOut(); }, 2500); document.location.href='/profile/'; }
                } //e

            });//d
        });//c
};//b

$('#submit').click(login);

}); //a
```

This all works fine and dandy ONLY if you click the sign in button(which is understandable being that the function only runs on 'click()'). How do I make it work so that if someone were to hit the enter key, it will work too? Sorry for the question being dumb. It would just be nice to let people use the enter key.

NOTE: There are 2 other forms on this page as well. So how could I make it that when I hit when they're in this DIV, it logs in? I was thinking something along the lines of

```
var emailCheck = $('#emailB').val();


if(emailCheck =='' && "enter button is clicked")
{
do nothing
}
elseif(emailCheck.length > 1 && "enter button is clicked")
{
login();
}
```

I don't know if this would be a dumb way of doing it, or somewhat logical.

Thanks a bunch!
-Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) use [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login_form').submit(function(){
        var emailB = encodeURIComponent($('#email_B').val());  
        var passwordB = encodeURIComponent($('#password_B').val());  
        $('#content').fadeOut();
        $('#login_effect').fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', url: 'checklogin.php',  dataType: "json",  data: { email: emailB, password: passwordB,  },
            success: function(result) {                
                if (!result.success) { timeout = setTimeout(function(){ $('#login_effect').fadeOut(); }, 2500); document.location.href='wrongpassword/'; } 
                else { timeout = setTimeout(function(){ $('#login_effect').fadeOut(); }, 2500); document.location.href='/profile/'; }
            } 
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $('#login_form').submit();
    });
});
```

And then change your HTML to:

```
<div id="login">
    <form id="login_form"> 
        <label for="email_B">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="email_B" id="email_B" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password_B" name="password_B" id="password_B" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign in" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: trying this now! THANK YOU for your time sir

Comment: Edited my answer, try the new solution :)

Comment: I can accept this an an answer in 2 minutes! thanks so much for your help. Really new to JQuery & JS, learning new functions everyday. This works awesome!

Comment: Make sure inside the #submit click function, you have: `$('#login_form').submit();` - I made an edit just before.

Comment: YUP! I got the edit. This works great, very excited. First Website I'm making using JQuery. Stack overflow helped me out like crazy along the way. Ya'll are awesome. Thanks again bro!

Comment: No problem, I only started a while a go too. Keep practicing, it's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can wireup `document.keyup` event to do this. Read more about it on [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) or `.keyup()` on [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/). You can use the `keyCode` value to identify if `enter` key is pressed

Hope this helps you.